# Querying multiple linked classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to query multiple tables. For example in posts table there is a user_id linked to users id. While showing every post, I also want to display the picture of the user. My approach is this, but there is a problem. `@user.picture` method is undefined.

```
<% @programs.each do |post| %>
<%= @user = User.where("id = post.user_id") %>
<li class="one-third column">                         
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="postThumb"><img src="<%= @user.picture %>" /></div>
  <div class="postDetails">
    <%= link_to "#{ post.title.upcase! }".html_safe, all_posts_path, :class => "postTitle" %>
    <p><%= truncate post.details, :length => 90 %></p>
  </div> 
</div>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Program Controller:

```
class ProgramController < ApplicationController
def index
  @programs = Program.all
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :password, :username, :oauth_token, :provider, :uid, :oauth_expires_at, :picture, :email, :name, :location, :gender, :updated_at, :is_admin
  has_many :posts   
  has_one :program
  has_many :programdetails, :through => :program
end
```

Program model:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :details, :title, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :programdetails
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead, in the controller:

```
@programs = Program.includes(:user) # this will return all programs and related users in
                                    # 2 database queries rather than N+1 queries
```

Then in the view:

```
<div class="postThumb"><img src="<%= post.user.picture %>" /></div>
```

Also, you can use [image_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) instead.

Finally, you can probably change your post title link to:

```
<%= link_to post.title.upcase, all_posts_path, :class => "postTitle" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@user = post.user`. Rails association will give back the associated user by itself.

And to correct above, syntactically, `@user = User.find(post.user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

try changing this: `@user = User.where("id = post.user_id")`

into this: `@user = User.where(id: post.user_id).first`

or even better: `@user = post.user` as suggested by kiddorails

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to do this using the relations you have already defined:

#### Programs Controller

```
def index
  @programs = Program.
    includes(:user). # eager load user relation to avoid n+1
    all
end
```

#### View

```
<% @programs.each do |post| %>
  <li class="one-third column">                         
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="postThumb"><img src="<%= post.user.picture %>" /></div>
        <div class="postDetails">
          <%= link_to "#{ post.title.upcase! }".html_safe, all_posts_path, :class => "postTitle" %>
          <p><%= truncate post.details, :length => 90 %></p>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
```